# Why does the constructor call depend on the default destructor's presence?

Tags: c++

In the following code, I get two constructor calls for `Test u = "u";`. However, if I comment out the destructor, then I only get one constructor call. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& t) -> decltype(t.print(os), os) 
{ 
    t.print(os); 
    return os; 
} 

class Test 
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Test(T&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "Test " << t << '\n';
    }
    ~Test() = default; // if commented out removes one construction
    void print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << "[with T = Test]";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test u = "u"; // two constructors (second, a temporary, with T = Test)
    Test t("t"); // one constructor
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking why `u` has two constructor calls while `t` has one?

Comment: Yes. And why does that become one when the default destructor is commented out?

Comment: Please formulate the question more clear, I can't see what you are asking.

Comment: And if you are asking about the actual number of constructors called inside `Test u = "u";`, you know it's implementation defined?

Comment: No. I have just started this new version of C++ and didn't realise the difference.

Comment: "new version of C++"?

Comment: New to me. I'm a few years behind everyone else.

Comment: Reopened.  That was the wrong dupe target.  Sorry

Comment: @SergeyA He has a templated constructor that takes anything.

Comment: It compiles and gives output:- http://ideone.com/85y0iv

Comment: @NathanOliver, true. My bad, need to read the code more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user-declared destructor, even if it is defaulted, means no move constructor gets generated.

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**
>
> 9 If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> [...]
>
> (9.4) -- `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

If a move constructor is generated, then it is a better candidate for moves than your template constructor. It doesn't save a constructor call, it just means a different constructor gets called, one that doesn't print anything.

Comment: I didn't realise that Test u = "u"; involved a move constructor as well. But I have now added the move constructor with and that doesn't get called.

Comment: @QuentinUK: There's still copy elision. Try with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I've added Test(const Test& t); declaration, and now it calls the other constructor twice either way. But this fn isn't even called (the definition can be removed.)

Comment: @QuentinUK Oh, there is actually something else I missed. Even though your template constructor with `T = Test` takes a `Test &&`, it's not a move constructor, and thus it doesn't allow copy elision. When you add a move constructor of your own, then copy elision does become allowed, which can explain why you still don't see it being called except if you specify the flag Kerrek SB noted.